# How can find CLIENT_KEY_PATH from console.developer.com?

Tags: php, google-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Here is what I did so far:

1. Installed the Google PHP API libraries.
2. Created a Google API project in the same account. I have no idea which API I need and which oAuth keys I need.
3. Installed the Google API Spreadsheet client from https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client.

Please anyone let me know how can find CLIENT_KEY_PATH? I have also try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470405/google-api-how-to-connect-to-receive-values-from-spreadsheet/22130673)

Answer (score 0):

Go into the [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) and in the respective project, under APIs and Auth -> Credentials, create a new ClientID for a Service Account. Creating a ClientID for Service Account should generate a JSON key file. Your CLIENT_KEY_PATH should point to that.

A basic service account authentication might look something like:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId(clientID);
$client->setApplicationName(applicationName);
$client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    clientEmail,
    array('https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://docs.google.com/feeds'),
    file_get_contents(CLIENT_KEY_PATH),
    clientKey
));
$client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
```