# Want to add new record/row in Google spreadsheet in PHP

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to add new records in Google spreadsheet by php coding. I had searched and found a solution which was using gmail id and password system for authentication. It was working initially but after 2 days it suddenly stop working. The code was as mentioned below:

```
<?php

include 'spreadsheet.php';
$Spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet("xxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxxx");
$Spreadsheet->setSpreadsheet("Tester")->setWorksheet("Sheet1")->add(array("First Name" => "Cell 1", "Last Name" => "Cell 2"));

?>
```

After it stops working I came to know that google has changed it's login system and I need to migrate to Oauth system for authentication.

After doing a long R & D I found one example - "https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client" . But it was not working and after combing my various source of searching I have develop the following code:

```
<?php

include_once "google-api-php-client/examples/templates/base.php";

/************************************************
  Make an API request authenticated with a service
  account.
 ************************************************/
require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php');

$accessToken = getGoogleTokenFromKeyFile("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

use Google\Spreadsheet\DefaultServiceRequest;
use Google\Spreadsheet\ServiceRequestFactory;

//ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance(new DefaultServiceRequest($accessToken));

// Load spreadsheet and worksheet
$worksheet = (new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService())
    ->getSpreadsheets()
    ->getByTitle('Sheet1')       // Spreadsheet name
    ->getWorksheets()
    ->getByTitle('Tester');      // Worksheet name
$listFeed = $worksheet->getListFeed();

// Uncomment this to find out what Google calls your column names
// print_r($listFeed->getEntries()[0]->getValues());

// Add a new blank row to the spreadsheet, using the column headings
$listFeed->insert(['name' => 'Simon', 'age' => 25, 'gender' => 'male']);

/**
 * Retrieves a Google API access token by using a P12 key file,
 * client ID and email address
 *
 * These three things may be obtained from 
 * https://console.developers.google.com/
 * by creating a new "Service account"
 */
function getGoogleTokenFromKeyFile($clientId, $clientEmail, $pathToP12File) {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId($clientId);

    $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $clientEmail,
        array('https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds'),
        file_get_contents($pathToP12File)
    );

    $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

    if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
    }

    $service_token = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
    return $service_token->access_token;
}


?>
```

But unfortunately this one is also not working and after sudden timeframe it is showing request time out error in my local xampp server.

And till date my application is on hold. Really not sure what to do now. If anybody has any concrete solution against that please share with me. my main purpose is to add data to google spreadsheet when a user submits his details in my website. Or if it is not possible after google's change in authentication system then please confirm me also. I want reachout a final solution of this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this library and the examples. It my help you with the OAuth part for your program: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2

Comment: not sure if you are still working on this; did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470405/google-api-how-to-connect-to-receive-values-from-spreadsheet/22130673#22130673

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to retrieve a valid token, then pass the token in the request header with "Bearer yourtokenstring". google changed this recently from "GoogleLogin auth=yourtokenstring". Use the Bearer tag instead.

If you are struggling in your effort to retrieve a valid access token, consider using a Service Account with a p12 key file. Grant Edit privileges to your spreadsheet to the service account email address.