# Get data with spaces from Google Spreadsheets (via PHP)

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

How I can get data from my Google Spreadsheet if it contains spaces?

Example: I have two columns: Person1 and Person2 and I need find a match names.

I read this [Google API How to connect to receive values from spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470405/google-api-how-to-connect-to-receive-values-from-spreadsheet)

And tried:

`$listFeed = $worksheet->getListFeed(array("sq" => "person1" . " = " . "Jon Doe"));`

and it's not working. I also tried `'Jon%20Doe'` but it's still not working. For rows without spaces in this field it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `"person1" . " = " . "Jon Doe"` that you assign to the `sq` key in your array results in a `"person1 = Jon Doe"` string. Here it is likely that `Jon Doe` isn't seen as a string of its own, as you would like it to be.

Maybe you could try to quote `Jon Doe` like this:

```
$listFeed = $worksheet->getListFeed(array("sq" => "person1 = 'Jon Doe'"));
```

Or like this:

```
$listFeed = $worksheet->getListFeed(array("sq" => 'person1 = "Jon Doe"'));
```

**Also**, make sure the column parameter in your query string (here `person1`) is consistent with your column name (`Person1`). Case mismatch might be why it fails.

Comment: Yea, just tried: $listFeed = $worksheet->getListFeed(array("sq" => 'person1' . ' = ' . '"Jon Doe"')); and it works!

Comment: Glad it helped!