# Add data with url to Google Spreadsheet (via PHP)

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm used this [Google API How to connect to receive values from spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470405/google-api-how-to-connect-to-receive-values-from-spreadsheet)

And tried add row with url:

```
$row=array(
      'downloadvideo' => '[link url="'.$this->linkVideo.'"]Download[/link]',
);

$listFeed->insert($row);
```

or

```
$row=array(
      'downloadvideo' => '[url '.$this->linkVideo.']Download[/link]',
);

$listFeed->insert($row);
```

But it's not working.

I need that user will see only word "Download", but after click — it's will open full http url. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution:

```
$row=array(
      'downloadvideo' => '=HYPERLINK("'.$this->linkVideo.'";"Download")',
);

$listFeed->insert($row);
```